# Can anyone show me how to make "Mailboxer"'s controller, model, view, and routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

First of all, thanks in adavance. 
This might be so noob question.

I already did setup devise and mailboxer. devise works completely fine!
Then "username" column is added to Users table, and I configured just like this

/config/initializers/mailboxer.rb

```
#Configures the methods needed by mailboxer
config.email_method = :email
config.name_method = :username
```

Now I'm totally stucked!! I don't know how to make the rest for simple message system.
What I want is these message function listed below

index(index/received or index/sent)... you can see the list of messages received(from/to, subjectes, and received date are only shown) 
show...you can see whole body of the message.
new... message create form, as an option, you can choose 'reply' from "show" page. in this case body text field already includes messages quotes.

Can someone make very simple example for me?
I can pay up to $50 for it via paypal!

I think I need to make 
"messages_controller"
"message" model if you needed with mailboxer gem
"view/messages/index", "view/messages/show", "view/messages/new"
"routes" has to be modified.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I assume you've resolved your issues by now, but for future reference, a sample app featuring the mailboxer gem is:

https://github.com/RKushnir/mailboxer-app

(not mine, but helpful to get up and going)

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yeah I used this example for my app, and it's working fine now:) Thanks anyway!